# adb - reach to get app names in android device (settings > apps) #python

Tags: python, adb, version, settings

I'm implementing a Python script to get some app names and their version numbers from settings>apps section in an android device.

First of all, I tried run `adb shell pm list packages` to see all packages. But I don't need all packages in this list, I need to list more specific apps and their versions. On the device, when I click to the settings > apps, there is an **apps information** section. This apps information section includes some apps I need.

How can I fetch list of applications and their versions that are in settings > apps using Python?

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: do you mean the list of "*recently opened apps*" ?

Comment: I'm trying to fetch list of  all apps in settings >apps section, not  the recently opened apps. @DiegoTorresMilano

Comment: I couldn't find anything to solve my problem. @Lino you have any idea ?